# React component is not rendering after state change with button click while using useContext hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I am using useContext hook for the first time as I wanted the re-rendering of one component by click of a button component. Here's my code:

QuestionContext.js (for creating context):

```
import { createContext } from "react";

const QuestionContext = createContext()

export default QuestionContext
```

SectionState.js (for providing value to children):

```
import {React, useState} from 'react'
import QuestionContext from './QuestionContext'
import questions from '../data/questions.json'


const SectionState = (props) => {
  
  // set questions from json to an array of 4 elements
  const newQuestions = Object.keys(questions.content).map(key => questions.content[key].question)
  
  const newState = {
    "qID": 0,
    "questionTxt": newQuestions[0],
  }
  
  //useState for Question state
  const [currentQuestion, setCurrentQuestion] = useState(0)
  const [questionCtx, setQuestionCtx] = useState(newState)
  
  const updateQuestion = () => {
    if(currentQuestion > newQuestions.length) {
      console.log("no more questions")
    }
    else{
      setCurrentQuestion(currentQuestion + 1)
      setQuestionCtx(() => ({
        "qID": currentQuestion,
        "questionTxt": newQuestions[currentQuestion]
      }))
    }
  } 
  
  return (
    <QuestionContext.Provider value = {{newState, updateQuestion}}>
      {props.children}
    </QuestionContext.Provider>
  )
}

export default SectionState
```

The following two components are child of `<SectionState />` component

Buttons.js:

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react'
import QuestionContext from '../context/QuestionContext'

const Buttons = () => {
  
    const example = useContext(QuestionContext)
    
    const clickHandler = () => {
        example.updateQuestion()
    }
  
    return (
    <div className='flex flex-row justify-between'>
        {/* <button className='btn backdrop-blur-md bg-slate-600 rounded-full xl:w-48 md:w-44 text-slate-50' onClick={ clickHandler }>Prev</button> */}
        <button className='btn btn-accent rounded-full xl:w-48 md:w-44' onClick={ clickHandler }>Next</button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Buttons
```

Questions.js

```
import { React, useContext } from 'react'
import './styles/Questions.css'
import QuestionContext from '../context/QuestionContext'

const Questions = () => {

  const newContext = useContext(QuestionContext)
  return (
    <>
      <h1 className='text-4xl text-zinc-50'>{ newContext.newState.questionTxt }</h1>
    </>
  )
}

export default Questions
```

Every time I have clicked on the button, I could check in the console that `newState` state has changed, but this new state won't render in `<Questions />` component. I could still see `newContext.newState.questionTxt` holding the initial value i.e. `newQuestions[0]`.  What am I doing wrong here?

Here's a reproduced [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-usecontext-0gl343?file=/src/App.js) in code sandbox

Comment: Can you just make a reproducible example in any sandbox?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-usecontext-0gl343?file=/src/App.js

Here's the link for the example produced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<QuestionContext.Provider value = {{newState, updateQuestion}}
```

Here you passed newState and updateQuestion as a value of context. In Button component you update currentQuestion and questionCtx using updateQuestion() but in Questions component, you are using the value of newState as

```
const newContext = useContext(QuestionContext)
<h1 className='text-4xl text-zinc-50'>{ newContext.newState.questionTxt }</h1>
```

Here newState is not a state. It is just a variable and it is not updated at all so you don't get an updated value in Question component.

Solution:
So I think you should pass the questionCtx as a value of context Provider like

```
<QuestionContext.Provider value = {{questionCtx , updateQuestion}}
```

Use it like

```
<h1 className='text-4xl text-zinc-50'>{ newContext.questionCtx.questionTxt }</h1>
```

**Working Codesandbox link:** https://codesandbox.io/s/react-usecontext-forked-frgtw1?file=/src/context/SectionState.js